# Ansible: execute command if value is arithmetic

Tags: ansible

I am using ansible for on of my project in which i want to execute command when the previous command returns me some value. Like I am checking the root folder and if files are found more than lets say 10, execute the next command.

I am trying to do this with ansbile in below manner. Pls help

```
---
- hosts: debug
  user: root

  tasks:
  - name: check if count ge 15
    command: bash -c "ls /root | wc -l"
    register: ifcount
    ignore_errors: True
  - debug: var=ifcount.stdout

 - name: create new file if above command sucessfull
    command: touch /tmp/file.html
    when: ifcount -ge 15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`when` is a Jinja2 expression. It uses Jinja2 [comparison](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#comparisons) operators.

Also note, that you try to compare `ifcount`, whereas actual value to compare is `ifcount.stdout`.

Try: `when: ifcount.stdout | int >= 15`

Comment: Thanks Suvorov. It did exactly i wanted. Thanks a ton.